# Python 3.7: Pygsheets get all record stopped working

Tags: python-3.x, pygsheets

I have several scripts using pygsheets to get information from google sheets. Today they have stopped working without any errors or exceptions being noted.

Debuging Attempts:

Tried running in different ways
   1. Visual Studio Code - just stops working no errors or exceptions. Debugged to line (wks = sh.worksheet('title', tabs)) 
   2. command prompt - pops a window up that states "Python has stopped working: A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program"
   3. manually in IDLE - locks up at (wks = sh.worksheet('title', tabs)) 
   4. Ran code on a different machine: worked fine.

So, I know it has to do with something on my machine, but not sure where to start looking. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
import pygsheets 
from pygsheets import Worksheet
gsheet = pygsheets.authorize(service_file = 'client_secret2.json')
sh = gsheet.open('Google_file_name')
wks = sh.worksheet('title', 'tab_name')
results = wks.get_all_records()
```

The last line is where everything stops. Again, no errors or exceptions.

Comment: I occasionally have the same issue with *gspread*'s `get_all_values` module.  For me, the issue comes and goes without any changes made to the code, which has lead me to believe it may be caused by a poor connection...?  Really not sure though.

Comment: Keep trying on both machines at different times of the day.  I'm relatively sure it's a connection issue.  Anything else would usually result in an error, and I have also experienced hang issues with unrefined TCP connections.

Comment: It seems to be isolated to one tab, which happened to be the first tab in the google spreadsheet. I am still not sure what in that tab changed to keep it from working correctly. I have looked for non-ansc II characters, but no luck so far.

Comment: I've had issues with tab name bug before, but it resulted in an error, not hanging.

Comment: I doubt a bug in gspread would be relevant to pygsheets anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really solve the issue, nor do I have experience with *pygsheets*, but from my experience with *gspread* the issue appears to be connection-related.  I have had this exact issue with *gspread*'s `get_all_values` module and, as you experienced, it suddenly stops working without any changes to the code and without terminating or returning any errors.  The issue often disappears when the program is run again minutes or days later.

The only other time I have experienced freezing/hanging (recently in Python) is with TCP connections...